# Calling Drools Agenda after completion of iteration of Arraylist in DRL file

Tags: iteration, drools

I am iterating a list in the DRL file. I need to call the new Agenda after completion of the loop. But the following code calls the Agenda "B to C" for all iterations

```
rule "Difference in offsets"
dialect "java"
lock-on-active
when
    $notification : NotificationVO()
    wtOffset:Integer() from $notification.getWeightOffset();
then
    System.out.println("Hello loop1");
    $notification.getOffsetChngesInterval().
    add((wtOffset-$notification.getInitialOffset()));
    update($notification);
    drools.setFocus("B to C");

rule "Last activity"
   dialect "java"
   salience 2
    no-loop true
    auto-focus false
    agenda-group "B to C"
when
     $notification:NotificationVO
     ($notification.getOffsetChngesInterval()!=null)
then
    System.out.println("Rule2---"+
    $notification.getOffsetChngesInterval().size());
end
```

In the above code i want to focus the agenda-group "B to C" only after completing the iteration of $notification.getWeightOffset();.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments. (1) The abundant usage of rule attributes is something to be avoided. (2) Rule "Difference in offsets" implements a procedural paradigm: map elements of one list to create another list.

That said, I'd do the calculation of the "changes intervals" on the right hand side of a rule that triggers when there are more "weight offsets" that "changes intervals". (I'm guessing that this is a good condition.)

```
rule "Difference in offsets"
dialect "java"
when
  $ntf: NotificationVO( weightOffset.size() > offsetChngesInterval.size(),
                        $initOff: initialOffset )
then
  for( Integer ioff: $ntf.getWeightOffset ){
    $ntf.getOffsetChngesInterval().add(ioff - $initOff );
  }
  update( $ntf );
  System.out.println( $ntf.getOffsetChngesInterval().size());
end
```